# Hide app that was launched on login on macOS 13 Ventura

Tags: macos, cocoa

Up until macOS 12, there was a checkbox labelled "Hide" for each login item in the Users & Groups System Preferences. Now in macOS 13 the login items have been moved to the General System Preferences, but the "Hide" checkbox has disappeared. Is there a way to know from within the app that it was launched as a login item, without offering an in-app "Launch at login" option which would allow me to control the whole process, but would be quite some effort to just replace that one little option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually decided to assume that if an app is among the login items, it should always be launched hidden. If the user launches it manually (from the Dock, Finder or Launchpad) then it is still hidden by default, but this scenario probably doesn't happen too often). Until Apple provides a way of checking if an app has been launched automatically at login, I don't want to spend time figuring out ways of doing such simple things.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let window = (NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "MainWindowController") as! NSWindowController).window!
        if #available(macOS 13.0, *) {
            if SMAppService.mainApp.status != .enabled {
                window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
            }
        } else {
            window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "it should always be launched hidden." < Meaning the app won't be on foreground on startup? 

" If the user launches it manually (from the Dock, Finder or Launchpad) then it is still hidden by default, but this scenario probably doesn't happen too often)." Meaning that if the user manually opens up the app, the app is still hidden, not on foreground? Then how does a user see the UI of an app?

Comment: Correct. If it's visible in the Dock, then clicking the Dock symbol shows the app, otherwise the app should probably have a status item that allows to show the UI. If it doesn't, then it probably doesn't make sense to hide it at all.